# CSS3 Translate % Units?

Tags: css-transforms

Here is what I want to do

a. I have a ball whose top edge is located 50% below the top of its container
b. I want to apply a translation that moves it do it sits on the floor of the contaienr

Here is what I tried

```
.ball
{
 position:absolute;
 left:25%;
 top:50%;
 height:80px;
 width:80px;
 -webkit-animation:fall 3.4s normal forwards ease-in-out;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fall
{
 0%{-webkit-transform:translateY(0%);}
 100%{-webkit-transform:translateY(100%);}
}
```

The end result I see is quite unexpected - measuring the extent of the drop with the PicPick pixel ruler indicates a drop of 80px i.e. 100% corresponds to the **height** of the ball. By using pixel units I can get the ball to drop through the precise pixel distance that I indicate but that is not quite what I need to do.

I suspect that I haven't quite fully understood the issues involved here.  I'd much appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer - that is in fact the right behavior.  If you want to use relative units in translate transforms consider using [viewport length units](http://caniuse.com/#search=viewport) instead.